# Does smart contract reside on every node after deploying?

Tags: contract-deployment

After deploying the smart contract,
it will be compiled as bytecode and run on EVM,
does the bytecode only belong to the deployer or the bytecode resides on the ledger shared by each node in the network(every node has the bytecode)?

Answer (score 2):

*in **short***  : The bytecode is stored in the blockchain in the contract's account. it belongs to '*nobady*' and every node could read the bytecode (while it has a blockchain copy) and execute in its VM.